# Unable to connect to anything using ssh

Tags: ssh, networking, openssh

I am trying to use ssh to connect to a server on 3 different thinkpads: T430s, E420, and a T400. SSH just hangs at `connecting to sdf.org [205.166.94.16] port 2` (sdf is a known working ssh server). I can telnet, ping, curl, and even telnet over port 22 sdf.org with no issues. I can also connect using my desktop which is on the same network. Here's the log when I run `ssh -vvv new@sdf.org`:

[image: trying to connect to sdf.org on the T430s]

I have tried connecting through different interfaces (WiFi as opposed to Ethernet). I also tried my phones hotspot and that did work, however I checked my routers configuration extensively and I checked with my ISP (Xfinity) to see if they were blocking any traffic.

Output of `ip route show`:

[image]

Output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

[image]

Pinging, curling, telneting, and telneting over port 22 on sdf.org:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/tangowhisky37/LetsHack/blob/master/howto/SSH-Hangs-On-Launch.md), some routers dislike the `IP_TOS` value set by `ssh`. You may check if that is the case by running:

```
ssh -o "IPQoS 0x00" -vvv new@sdf.org
```

If that works, you can avoid typing it all the time by adding that option (without the quotes, just `IPQoS 0x00`) to the relevant portion of your `ssh` config file (e.g. `$HOME/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`).

As a curiosity, in your system the `IP_TOS` (yes, the kernel code calls it `IP_TOS`, while the OpenSSH option is `IPQoS`) is set to 0x48 (`IPTOS_PREC_IMMEDIATE` + `IPTOS_THROUGHPUT`)—either in a config file or that is the default in your `openssh` package—while in mine (Ubuntu 22.04 with OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022) the default is just 0x10 (`IPTOS_LOWDELAY`).

If you want to experiment with other values, [you can find them here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/ip.h#L25).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This fixed it perfectly. Not sure why my system (Artix linux with openssh 9.0p1) has it set differently, but I am glad it works now.